# Don't select that row in a table in which a column data is mapped by second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the result from two table. The table are as follows:-

**Table 1:** Tags -

```
tagid          tagname

 1            science
 2            technology
 3            art
 4            culture
 5            space
 6            fashion
```

**Table 2:** usersAndTags

```
tagid          userid

 6               23
 2               97
 4               23
 4               97
 3               56
 6               23
```

Table `tags` contains `tagid` and `tagname`. Table `userAndTags` contains the `tagid` and `userid`. A row of `userAndTags` shows a user with that userid follows that tag.

I want the `tagname` and `tagid` from table `tags` which is not being followed by `userid` 23. What will be sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `not exists`

```
select *
from tags t
where not exists (select 1 from usersandtags 
                  where t.tagid=tagid 
                  and userid=23)
```

or a `left join`.

```
 select t.*
 from tags t
 left join usersandtags u on u.tagid=t.tagid and u.userid=23
 where u.tagid is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` like

```
select t.tagid,
t.tagname
from tags t
left join usersAndTags ut on t.tagid  = ut.tagid          
and ut.userid = 23
where ut.tagid is null;
```